# Fill blank cells from above in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I have this VBA code.  I want to fill in blank cells with the vakue above but only if the above cell is not a table header. It works user can select range of cells the code create a table if is not a table already. Maybe there woupd be better way like create the table if user click a cell somewhere in the table. the issue is that It will fill in blank cells with the value from above cell as intended but if there is a blank in the second row then it copies the header there  I want to avoid that so I added a condition with function but the I get an error on the line where a cell is checked if it is a header

here is the full code

```
Sub FillBlankCells()
 
    ' Prompt user to select a range of cells
    Dim selRange As Range
    Set selRange = Application.InputBox("Please select a range of cells to turn into a table:", Type:=8)
   
    ' Check if a table already exists in the selected range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    On Error Resume Next
    Set tbl = selRange.ListObject
    On Error GoTo 0
   
    ' If a table doesn't exist, create a new table
    If tbl Is Nothing Then
        Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, selRange, , xlYes)
    End If
   
    ' Loop through each column in the table
    Dim col As ListColumn
    For Each col In tbl.ListColumns
       
        ' Loop through each row in the column
        Dim row As Range
        For Each row In col.Range.Rows
           
            ' If cell is blank and above cell is not a table header, fill with value from cell above
            If IsEmpty(row.Value) And Not IsTableHeader(row.Offset(-1, 0), tbl) Then
                row.Value = row.Offset(-1, 0).Value
            End If
           
        Next row
       
    Next col
   
End Sub
 
Function IsTableHeader(cell As Range, tbl As ListObject) As Boolean
    ' Check if cell is a table header
    If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
        If cell.Address = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1).Address Then
            IsTableHeader = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
   
    IsTableHeader = False
End Function
```

Comment: What do you want happening if the empty cell is just bellow the header? To let it blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your code doing nothing in case **of a blank cell bellow the header**, please use the next adapted code, keeping from it as mutch as I could. It extracts the table `DataBodyRange`, resize it to exclude its first row and process it without any helping function:

```
Sub FillBlankCells()
    ' Prompt user to select a range of cells
    Dim selRange As Range
    Set selRange = Application.InputBox("Please select a range of cells to turn into a table:", Type:=8)
   
    ' Check if a table already exists in the selected range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    On Error Resume Next
    Set tbl = selRange.ListObject
    On Error GoTo 0
   
    ' If a table doesn't exist, create a new table
    If tbl Is Nothing Then
        Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, selRange, , xlYes)
    End If
    
    Dim dataBR As Range
    Set dataBR = tbl.DataBodyRange
    Set dataBR = dataBR.Resize(dataBR.rows.count - 1).Offset(1)
      'Debug.Print dataBR.address: Stop 'just to see the range to be processed address
    
    ' Loop through each column in the table
    Dim col As Range, row As Range
    For Each col In dataBR.Columns
        ' Loop through each row in the column
        For Each row In col.rows
            ' If cell is blank and above cell is not a table header, fill with value from cell above
            If IsEmpty(row.Value) Then
                row.Value = row.Offset(-1, 0).Value
            End If
        Next row
    Next col
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your (inner) loop starts at the first row of the column (the header row). If the table starts in Row 1 of the sheet, you will access row 0 with the statement `IsTableHeader(row.Offset(-1, 0)` and that throws an error.

I would suggest that your inner loop starts with the 3rd row of the table (the first row is the header, the 2nd shouldn't be changed as you don't want to copy the header). The `IsTableHeader` function is no longer needed.

```
' Loop through each column in the table
Dim col As ListColumn
For Each col In tbl.ListColumns
    ' Loop through each row in the column
    Dim cell As Range, row As Long
    For row = 3 To col.Range.Rows.Count
        Set cell = col.Range(row, 1)
        ' If cell is blank and above cell is not a table header, fill with value from cell above
        If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next row
Next col
```

Answer (score 0):

### Fill Blanks in Table (ListObject)

```vb
Dim col As ListColumn, cell As Range, IsFirstFound As Boolean

For Each col In tbl.ListColumns
    For Each cell In col.DataBodyRange.Cells
        If IsFirstFound Then
            If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
            End If
        Else
            IsFirstFound = True
        End If
    Next cell
    IsFirstFound = False ' reset for the next iteration (column)
Next col
```